# 日付データから、月、日にちのデータを作成したい

Tags: python, pandas

日付データから、月、日にちのデータを作成したく、次のようなコードを準備しています。

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['Fri, 10 Mar 2017 23:58:00 GMT',
           'Sat, 11 Mar 2017 05:33:42 GMT',
           'Sat, 18 Mar 2017 04:51:13 GMT']})


date = pd.to_datetime(df["x"])
```

このデータから、次のようなデータフレームを作成したいのですが、
ここから先に難渋しており、どなたか、ご教示して頂けると、ありがたいです。。
よろしくお願いします。

```
year  month   date
2017    3       10
2017    3       11
2017    3       18
```

Comment: 参考: [Which is the fastest way to extract day, month and year from a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21954923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな書き方もできます

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['Fri, 10 Mar 2017 23:58:00 GMT',
           'Sat, 11 Mar 2017 05:33:42 GMT',
           'Sat, 18 Mar 2017 04:51:13 GMT']})

date_df = pd.to_datetime(df["x"]).apply(lambda d: pd.Series([d.year,d.hour,d.day], index=['Year','Month','Day']))

print(date_df)
#   Year  Month  Day
#0  2017     23   10
#1  2017      5   11
#2  2017      4   18
```

Comment: lambda関数を使って、コンパクトに書く方法のご教示、お礼申し上げます。

Answer (score 3):

`Series.dt`を使って

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
result['year'] = date.dt.year
result['month'] = date.dt.month
result['day'] = date.dt.day
```

Comment: このようなやり方もあるのですね！参考になります。

Answer (score 1):

頂いたコメントを元に、コードを作成したところ、できました。
コードを添付します。

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['Fri, 10 Mar 2017 23:58:00 GMT',
           'Sat, 11 Mar 2017 05:33:42 GMT',
           'Sat, 18 Mar 2017 04:51:13 GMT']})


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["x"])

df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day

print(df)
```